# How to place an image and a paragraph on PDF document header?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm trying to place an image and a text below this image on document header using `MigraDoc`.

Unfortunately I'm unable to do so. It seems to only be accepting image or paragraph but not both.

This is what I've tried:

```
var image = section.Headers.Primary.AddImage("image.jpg");
var text = section.Headers.Primary.AddParagraph("title");
```

It may be possible that paragraph is placed under image, making it invisible. It doesn't seem to be the case though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add images to paragraphs - you add the image to the header without a paragraph.

I'd try putting image and text into the same paragraph with a linebreak between them.

Untested code:

```
var para = section.Headers.Primary.AddParagraph();
var image = para.AddImage("image.jpg");
para.AddLineBreak();
para.AddText("title");
```

Comment: I think this will work. I tested it at some point and it was near to what I needed, missed the line break thing to make it look as I want. I'll test it tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: It worked :) I have a different related challenge though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983060/how-to-make-room-for-the-header-on-pdf-document